# Target machine actively refused it. Selenium for Ruby installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, installation

I'm not sure really where to begin in solving this.

In my command prompt (Windows 7) I typed `gem install selenium-webdriver`

and get in response `ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'selenium-webdriver' (>= 0), here is why: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)`

I have **Ruby** installed, but I have never used it before. Someone told me this is all I would need to do to get **selenium** for Ruby. Where did I go wrong? I'm pretty sure this has to do with a firewall hat runs on our work computers. How exactly should I go about resolving this?

Thanks in advance (but there will be more to come)!

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into a similar problem with my company's proxy. The trick was to authenticate with that server before trying to install the gem. I use any browser to browse to http://www.google.com, my proxy prompts me for authentication (which I enter), and then I have a session with the proxy and can freely download gems. Your mileage may vary.

Another possible thing to try is switching your gem source to the non-SSL version of that URL - `http://rubygems.org/`. However, if it's a firewall thing, it seems like the non-SSL version would be blocked, not the other way around.

**Edit**

To change your gem sources, use the `gem sources` command. `gem help sources` gives you a list of possible arguments, and `gem sources` gives you a list of your current gem sources. You want to run the following two commands to change from SSL to non-SSL:

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

You can also install gems manually from the .gem files. To do this, either download the .gem file from somewhere on the internet or install the gem on a different computer and copy it across. If you install it on a different computer, the .gem file can be found at `%RUBY_HOME%\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\cache\selenium-webdriver-2.35.1.gem` (note the full path will be slightly different for older ruby versions).

To install the gem on your new system, `cd` to the folder where you've downloaded the .gem file and run `gem install selenium-webdriver-2.35.1.gem`.

Comment: Hmm, when I open a browser it doesn't prompt me for any kind of authorization, or were you talking about doing that some other way? Non-SSL is worth a try, how do I change that? Also, is it possible just to install it not from my command prompt?